# Using Regex to find everything after a pattern BUT excluding a variable

Tags: python, regex, search, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am using the following code to try and search for text that comes after **data-bhc=**

But I also want to exclude the variable **new_deal** from coming after **data-bhc**. In this case the new_deal variable can be text like so: "deal:statler-grill-4"

This regex works when I am not trying to exclude a variable.

For example:

```
'<figure class=\"deal-card deal-list-tile deal-tile deal-tile-standard\" data-bhc="(.+?)"'
```

But when I am, my syntax forces my search to return none. What is the silly mistake?

```
regex = "<figure class=\"deal-card deal-list-tile deal-tile deal-tile-standard\" data-bhc=" + "^(?!" + re.escape(new_deal) + ").*"

pattern = re.compile(regex) 

info = re.search(pattern,htmltext)
print info.groups()
```

Comment: The question makes perfect sense. They need a regex that will match a pattern where the negative lookahead depends on the value of the string variable `new_deal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue may have something to do with how you are using single quotes `'` and double quotes `"`. If you know all quotes in your htmltext are going to be double quotes, define your regex as a string in single quotes.

This might work for you:

```
regex = '<figure class="deal-card deal-list-tile deal-tile deal-tile-standard" data-bhc="(?!'+ new_deal + ').*"'
```

Comment: I think this was close because I am no longer getting an error kick back but I am getting back: ()
I tried info.groups(0) but still get this empty parenthesis

Comment: @user2218297 Try `print info.group(0)` instead of `groups` (remove the s)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex includes a `^` in front of where you escape `new_deal`.  This will force the regex to look for lines where the start is `new_deal`.

Try:

```
"data-bhc=(?! *" + re.escape(new_deal) + ").*";
```

Unless data-bhc shows up a lot in your searched text, you can probably make the above the entire regex. Otherwise, just swap this in for your `new_deal` escape lookahead.

**EDIT:** I Also added a space possibility in front of your negative lookahead. This will block `new_deal` even if there is a space (or several) in front of it.

Comment: Yeah it does come up alot... I tried using the above and still not getting any matches :/ Error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
@adam yost

Comment: Maybe I am not capturing the new_deal variable properly... for now I have it hard coded as new_deal = "deal:statler-grill-4"
So I should be getting the very next match besides the statler-grill-4 since I am using re.search